# Explain after *r=*q

Tags: c++

Not able to understand int *r=*q; and (*r)++;(Here,r is a pointer pointing to an integer on LHS after = sign,how to form the analogy?)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a=100;
    int *p=&a;
    int **q=&p;
    int b=(**q)++;
    int *r=*q;
    ++(*r);


    cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Try stepping through the code in your debugger, and inspect the variables at each line.

Comment: It's effectively the same as  `int *r = p;`, which is effectively the same as `int *r = &a;`

Comment: `*r=*q` initalize `r` to a pointer to `a`, then `++(*r);` deference `r` and increment the value, thus `a` will be `101`.

Comment: When figuring out pointers, it will help to draw a picture.

Answer (score 4):

If we lay it out somewhat graphically, after the definition and initialization of `q` it would look something like this

```
+---+     +---+     +---+
| q | --> | p | --> | a |
+---+     +---+     +---+
```

That is `q` points to `p` which in turn points to `a`.

Now if we dereference `q` we get `p`.

So the initialization of `r` is equivalent to

```
int *r = p;
```

I.e. the above graph now looks like

```
+---+     +---+       +---+
| q | --> | p | --/-> | a |
+---+     +---+  |    +---+
                 |
          +---+  |
          | r | -/
          +---+
```

Dereferencing `r` (or `p`) gives you the variable `a` and its value. So doing e.g. `++(*r)` is the same as `++(*p)` which is the same as `++(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

To add up to the other answers: since you are using C++, you might want to write the pointer types as `int* r` instead of `int *r` and "link" the star to `int` instead of `r` on the left-hand side.

On the other hand, when not declaring a new variable, `*` means dereferencing, so `*q` gives you access to the value which `q` points to.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int a=100;
    int *p=&a;
    // p -> a = 100

    int **q=&p;
    // q -> p -> = 100

    int b=(**q)++;
    // b equals q dereferenced twice, then incremented. So b = a++ = 101


    int *r=*q;
    // *r equals q dereferenced once. So *r = p

    ++(*r);
    // r is dereferenced. So *r = *p = a = 100
}
```